# How to export large table from Teradata

Tags: teradata

What would be the best way to export large table (e.g. over 10 billion rows) from Teradata? In terms of speed and resources consumption.

I know FastExport tool which uses fastexport mode, but it still requires the results to be put in the spool before sending to the client. Before it allowed avoiding spool by forcing nospoolonly mode but this seems to be broken in recent releases. Therefore if I use it with `select * from table` query the whole table will be copied, which would require massive spool file allowance.

I also came across JDBC driver and PT API, however they seem to be using the same underlying mechanisms.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you think NOSPOOLONLY is broken? If it is, open an incident. Btw, FastExport is legacy, you should move to TPT EXPORT.

Comment: @dnoeth The bug is already filed [here](https://support.teradata.com/community/community?id=kb_article&sys_id=013732801b45c0d480c3c9176e4bcb82) (not by me). I noticed nospool mode is not allowed by default in e.g. 16.20 release. Thanks for the tip regarding TPT. I've seen that name before but I had the impression that the FastExport succeeded it. But it seems it's the other way round. However that bug I linked above mentions the same problem with nospool mode is in TPT.

Comment: Until NoSpool mode is available for FastExport *protocol* (regardless of the client utility using that interface), there is no way to export data without creating a spool with the results first.

Comment: @Fred Thanks for the explanation. Actually I must say it's quite confusing to me what tools are using what protocols. As from the outside some tools look like completely different technologies but I have the impression that internally it's all the same protocol. I.e. connection through ODBC, JDBC, bteq, fastexport, tpt seems to be using the same internal mechanisms - is that correct?

Comment: There is the "normal" SQL request protocol which is used for most things regardless of the client driver API. There are special "utility" protocols originally developed for FastExport, FastLoad, and MultiLoad  (and now used by TPT Export, Load, and Update operators respectively) plus some other special interfaces for Monitor requests and Backup/Restore operations. The Teradata utilities use a low-level CLIv2 driver, but some client drivers extend a standard API (e.g. JDBC) by providing Teradata-specific functions/methods that allow applications to leverage some of those other protocols.