# How to fetch all data from a very large table?

Tags: teradata

I'm wondering what would be the best approach, in terms of performance and memory consumption, to fetch all data from a very large table in Teradata - both UPI and NUPI? E.g. with over 10 billion rows. Provided that I can't just run `select * from table` as the spool size is way smaller than the size of the table.

For smaller tables with unique columns (like UPI) I can use pagination repeating query like that `select top PAGESIZE * from table where id > LASTVAL order by id`. However this does not seem suitable for large tables as sorting seems taking ages. And it would not work for tables without unique columns.

I noticed most of the large tables in production environments are NUPI tables. Therefore I was trying to come up with the following strategy: to export first all distinct PI values with corresponding row count to a temporary table and use that table to get PI values I could use for pagination. That would probably work fine for tables with low PI cardinality, e.g. 1 million distinct PI values in a table of 10 billion rows. However in case of very high cardinality the temporary table would still be quite large and may not fit in the spool.

I previously tried to play with the export functionality ([How to export large table from Teradata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66554403/how-to-export-large-table-from-teradata)) however due to the fact I cannot use nospoolonly mode this does not seem to help in my case.

I don't really care about data consistency at the moment - let's assume the table to be queried will be not updated during the fetching process.

Comment: Break it into chunks maybe?  Work with your DBAs to increase spool (temporarily)? Do you really need to export this entire table? What on earth are you going to do with a 10 billion row file?

Comment: @Andrew What do you exactly mean by breaking it into chunks? And how to achieve that? Unfortunately I need to export all data from the table (order of rows is irrelevant) to feed a third party tool that does some measurements. Increasing a spool to the size of the whole table is not an option.

Comment: Is your table partitioned? Do you have a date column you could use to run a year at a time? Stuff like that. Due to the bug with nospool, there doesn't seem to be a way around it - your extract has to fit in your spool. So your extract has to be smaller, your spool larger, or both.

Comment: @Andrew That's an interesting hint. It does not fully address my problem as my goal is eventually to create a script that will fetch data from all tables in a server regardless their size and schema. But I believe it's worth investigating the date columns. Thanks.